# How to set route53 Alias Target for a domain to a ec2 instance IP instead of load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I am trying to configure route53 A record for a domain in its hosted zone using the Alias Target drop down  i can see the following options like

- S3 website endpoints
- ELB Application load balancers,
- ELB Classic load balancers,ELB
- Network load balancers,
- CloudFront distributions,
- Elastic Beanstalk environments,
- VPC Endpoints,
- API Gateway APIs,
- Record sets in this hosted zone

My application doesn't need a load balancer and is running in a single EC2 instance i wanted to provide the Alias target to the instance public IP instead of hard coding the instance public ip in the A record set. Because the public IP is  ephemeral and gets changed after every restart.

one way to do this is to reserve a elastic IP and associate with a ENI and attach it to the ec2 instance and put the reserved elastic IP as A record in the record set.

Is there any other way to put the reserved elastic IP or instance ip as Alias Target in route53 record set.